# Mysql connection in Ansi c

Tags: c, c89

I am working in Ansi C, windows platform. I want to attach mysql database to my c program. Kindly guide me how I can make it possible.

Comment: Follow this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html) is a working example which sets up a connection and performs a query.

Comment: Thanks Stacker for your link.. Actually i working on window platform and I have wamp server for mysql database, I there any way to connect my c application with wamp server.

Comment: The source code is the same on windows, you just need to compile it differently - which is pretty much just a matter of setting include paths and libraries to link to.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI (ISO) C doesn't do networking, so by definition you *can't* do MySQL connections in ANSI C.  You will have to move to POSIX at least.  So, the answer is, "It is impossible."

Comment: I widows platform which lib I have to include instead of POSIX?

Comment: @Arman: you will need MySQL C library: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html.  But your question mentioned ANSI C.  You can't do it in ANSI C, although I don't know if you really require ANSI C or you just said that without understanding what it meant.  Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads and download the windows version for the library, and read their documentation.

Comment: I know POSIX is not the standard library, I want to use standard libraries, but in those cases in which ANSI doesn't support, I have to go to other libraries which is non-standard.

Comment: For writing MySQL client code in C, the MySQL C libraries are going to be the most portable.  They are available for a variety of systems.